# Replace not working on special characters

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

I have some info saved in a database field with the following structure:

```
First Name: > XXX
Last Name: > XXX
Sex: Male > Female
Age: 19 > 20
```

This information reflects changes made to a specific database record. In this example, First Name was changed from nothing to XXX, Last Name from nothing to XXX, Sex from Male to Female, and Age from 19 to 20. In order to clean up the first two entries and take out the unnecessary ">", I have the following simple Replace function:

```
Replace(objRS("action_info"),": > ",": ")
```

But for some reason, it's not working. It works when I try it with letters, for example, but it doesn't seem to want to bite with just the series of special characters and spaces. I even tried using all ASCII codes, but that didn't work either...

Comment: Slap this in the .vbs file an execute it: `MsgBox Replace("First Name: > XXX", ": > ", ": ")` . Does it work?  Does on my machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. There were two spaces between the : and the >.

D'OH!

Answer (score 0):

Does `Replace(objRS("action_info"),": &gt; ",": ")` do the trick?

Comment: Oh well - worth a try - fingers crossed someone will suggest something!